# Retrieving from a URL with many reserved characters via curl or HTTParty from Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, url, curl

I have a [Digital object identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) that has a bunch of URI reserved characters in it:

> 10.1002/(SICI)1096-9861(19960304)366:2<270::AID-CNE7>3.0.CO;2-2

I am attempting to pull bibliographic data from a DOI resolution API using this DOI. The URL scheme for the API is `http://dx.doi.org/DOIHERE`. Some headers may also be included to specify the format of the response. When I paste the URL `http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9861(19960304)366:2<270::AID-CNE7>3.0.CO;2-2` directly into the Chrome address bar, it works fine and I am redirected to a page appropriate for the article. However, I am unable to get the same response using this URL either in `curl` on the command line or in a Ruby script, or using Ruby's HTTParty gem. I have tried manually %-encoding all special characters and have the same issue:

```
url1 = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-9861(19960304)366:2<270::AID-CNE7>3.0.CO;2-2"
url2 = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002%2F%28SICI%291096-9861%2819960304%29366%3A2%3C270%3A%3AAID-CNE7%3E3.0.CO%3B2-2"
headers = { "Accept" => 'application/x-bibtex;q=1.0' }

`curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex;q=1.0" -i #{url1}`  # empty string response
`curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex;q=1.0" -i #{url2}`  # 504 Gateway timeout error
HTTParty.get url1, headers: { "Accept" => 'application/x-bibtex;q=1.0' }  # Ruby throws InvalidURI error
HTTParty.get url2, headers: { "Accept" => 'application/x-bibtex;q=1.0' }  # blank response body
```

Also, running Ruby's `URI.escape` on `url1` escapes only the angle brackets, leaving the parentheses, semicolon, and colon in place despite their status as reserved characters. Can someone explain what is going on here and how I can programatically retrieve from this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `H "Accept: application/x-bibtex;q=1.0"` from your request. From browser when you browse the link, you did not specify this header. So, do not require to specify from the curl.

Below one works perfectly with me:

```
curl -LH  -i -v "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002%2F%28SICI%291096-9861%2819960304%29366%3A2%3C270%3A%3AAID-CNE7%3E3.0.CO%3B2-2"
```